# If $|\,f'(p)|<1$, prove that $p$ is an attracting fixed point for $f$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, convergence-divergence, fixed-point-theorems

Suppose that $f:(a,b) \to (a,b)$ has a fixed point $p$ in $(a, b)$ and that $f$ is differentiable at $p$. Furthermore, assume that $|\,f'(p)|<1$.

**Question:** How do I prove that $p$ is an *attracting* fixed point for $f$.

I know that $p$ is an attracting fixed point for $f$ if there exists a $0<\delta<1$ such that $|\,f(x) - p|<|x - p|$ whenever $|x - p|<\delta, x \neq p$. I've tried to think of what the relationship of the derivative of $f$ with the fixed point $p$ would be, but I'm kind of stuck..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are told that
$$
f'(p) = \lim_{x\to p}\frac{f(x) - f(p)}{x-p}
$$
exists, and also told that $-1<f'(p)<1$. By using the definition of limit, this means that there is a $\delta>0$ such that for any $x\in (p-\delta, p+\delta)$ (in other words, any $x$ with $|x-p|<\delta$) we have
$$
-1<\frac{f(x) - f(p)}{x-p}<1 \iff\left|\frac{f(x) - f(p)}{x-p}\right|<1
$$
The defining property of attacting fixed point follows immediately from this.

Comment: I know this is an old post but I'm not sure how $|[f(x) - f(p)]/(x-p)| < 1$ follows from the definition of the limit. It was my understanding that this only implies that $|[f(x) - f(p)]/(x-p) - f'(p)| < 1$ which would at most imply that $|[f(x) - f(p)]/(x-p)| < 2$

Comment: @KirkFox Don't use $\varepsilon=1$. Use $\varepsilon$ such that $|f'(p)|+\varepsilon<1$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response. This was immensely helpful in proving that there exists some interval $I$ around $p$ such that $f(x) \in I$ for all $x \in I$.